# how to use dojo within a chrome extension?

Tags: dojo, google-chrome-extension

I want to use dojo within a chrome extension's content script. I have this in my manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts":[
{
    "js":["lib/dojo/dojo.js","main.js"],
    "matches":["<all_urls>"],
    "run_at": "document_idle"
}
]
```

I've already put a dojo folder under "lib" folder of the root of this extension. However, the script paused execution and told me dojo is undefined. This means dojo is not loaded.

then i tried register dojoConfig before dojo.js is loaded:

```
    "content_scripts":[
    {
        "js":["env.js",
        "lib/dojo/dojo.js",
        "main.js"],
        "matches":["<all_urls>"],
        "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
    ],
```

in the env.js, it contains;

```
dojoConfig = {
"baseUrl" : "/lib/dojo"
};
```

still not work though. Anyone else has sucessful experience?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

*These are injected in the order they appear in this array.*

Maybe your should have to change the js files list order

Comment: the issue is like dojo can not run in an chrome extension

Comment: the issue is like dojo can not run in chrome extension enviroment. It sounds like only support ff-ext